# Motorbike brake pedal not working

Tags: brakes

I’ve just replaced the brake fluid on my Mash Black Seven 125.
The front brake works well off the leaver but the pedal does nothing.
It still has pressure and does not feel soft but doesn’t make either brake work.
It’s a linked system which I guess may complicate matters.
I’m now super frustrated!
Can anyone offer a possible explanation or solution.

Comment: Did you follow the manufacturer's procedure to bleed the brakes?

Comment: It could be to do with bleeding. I’m going to try again. 
It’s just confusing that the pedal is firm rather than soft as it would usually be with trapped air.

Comment: Also, when I pump the pedal with the bleed nipple open, nothing comes out.

Comment: That sounds like its seized, or there's some sort of block in the line.

Comment: Perhaps the latter. It worked before I change the oil.